# CSS dropdown menu cutoff

Tags: css, menu

First time poster!  Longtime Stack Overflow lurker, trying this out:

I'm styling a CSS menu, and I'm having trouble applying my default styles to the sub-SUB-menu in the `<ul>` list.  You can see what I've got right now in this JS Fiddle below.  If you hover over Item 2, the dropdown list that appears is what I'm after, but if you then hover over Item 4, you can see what I'm getting with the next ul.

Is anyone able to spot the flaw in my CSS?  Much thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/b7den1s1/

```css
.new-menu {
  background-image: url("/images/logo.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.new-menu ul,
div.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.new-menu li,
div.menu li {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.new-menu ul li {
  background-image: url("/images/small-bar.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.new-menu li li,
.new-menu li li li {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  background-image: none;
}
.new-menu li a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.new-menu ul ul,
.new-menu ul ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 99999;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.new-menu ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99999999;
}
.new-menu a {
  color: #aaa;
  display: block;
  line-height: 41px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.new-menu ul li:hover > ul,
.new-menu ul ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
.new-menu li:hover > a,
.new-menu ul li:hover > a,
.new-menu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.new-menu ul ul a,
.new-menu ul ul ul a {
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="new-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
              </ul>
        </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, I welcome any pointers on how to properly style my question posed here.  I know the CSS code I posted is incomplete, but I had to manually indent the entire thing to get it into the code box, and it was becoming too time-consuming.

Comment: If you have the code someplace with the proper spacing in it you can: paste the code into the editor, select it so it's highlighted, then click on the code sample button `{}`. It will add the spacing to make it formatted as code. Alternatively, for HTML/CSS/JavaScript code you can click on the snippet button `<>` and paste your code there. That will make it a runnable snippet.

Comment: Either way, having enough code in the question itself to duplicate the error is a requirement, though it looks like someone's probably editing it into the question now.

Comment: Got it.  Thecommish3 is improved for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `width` to 100% in this class `.new-menu ul ul ul{...}`

```css
.new-menu {
    background-image: url("/images/logo.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.new-menu ul,
    div.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
 
.new-menu li,
    div.menu li {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.new-menu ul li {
    background-image: url("/images/small-bar.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    //margin-right: 15px;
}

.new-menu li li,
.new-menu li li li {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-image: none;
}

.new-menu li a {white-space:nowrap;}

.new-menu ul ul,
.new-menu ul ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left:auto;
    right:0;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.new-menu ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999999;
}

.new-menu a {
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    line-height: 41px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.new-menu ul li:hover > ul,
.new-menu ul ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.new-menu li:hover > a,
.new-menu ul li:hover > a,
.new-menu ul ul li:hover > a {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.new-menu ul ul a,
.new-menu ul ul ul a {
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="new-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
              <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
            </ul>
        </ul>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Officially in love with stackoverflow.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the following:

```
.new-menu li a {white-space:nowrap; display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, **thecommish3**!

**TL;DR**

No need to add more lines of code as other users are suggesting - just remove `right: 0;` from the following:

```
.new-menu ul ul,
.new-menu ul ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left:auto;
  right:0; /* Remove this rule! */
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 99999;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

**Longer answer if you're curious as to how I figured this out**

I put together a fiddle of what might be a better way of formatting this code at http://jsfiddle.net/myf4emyx/7/ that takes into account:

- Using classnames eg `.menu {}` instead of applying rules to elements eg `ul {}`
- [BEM-like naming conventions](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/) that allow for:

  - Better readability of code structure - you can see what's going on!
  - Encourages you to write classnames to target specific elements eg `.menu-item--sub`, rather than resorting to specificity eg `ul ul li`. This means you have one class for one rule (or group of rules) rather than a confusing and easy-to-break [specificity chain](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)
- Reusable components eg `.menu`, `.item-link` - less lines of CSS and less headache-inducing :)
- Better HTML formatting eg indentation, closing tags eg `<li><a>Link</a></li>`
- CSS shorthand eg `background: #fff url("/images/logo.gif") no-repeat left;`

After improving the formatting, structure & naming of your code I was able to diagnose the issue easily!

My main aim is to save you headaches in the future - on occasion, I've cursed the past-me for writing code that I just couldn't understand after spending some time away from it, so I try to write code that is as 'maintainable' as possible, ie, future-me can look at it a year from now and still understand what's going on (and possibly other people get involved with no prior knowledge and understand what's going on too).

Feel free to ignore, otherwise hope it helps - and please get in touch if you want to know more about any of the things I've mentioned above, or have any questions about the code in my fiddle.

Comment: "Current Me" is definitely "Past You" - I tend to keep beefing up the code I start with, and then tweaking it, until by the end it's almost unrecognizable.  And you're right - if I ever have to come back to it, it's pretty difficult to figure out what I was doing originally.

I'm totally stealing most of your freely-offered advice and code.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Belated realization - With this menu, unfortunately, I'm setting up a menu in Wordpress, so all the "ul li ul" stuff is a necessary evil, unless I want to manually add the CSS class names to each menu item in the Wordpress menus UI.